# How to make a user not being able to publish his content?

Tags: nodes

how is this possible to make a user/role not being able to publish content he has created ,but to be able to create new (unpublished) content?
thanks

Comment: Workbench moderation module has a lot of configuration options for publishing workflows. Perhaps that would help? https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing the same is using the [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) and set the node to unpublish for certain users/roles as below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */
function MyModule_node_presave($node) {
  global $user;
  $user_id = $user->uid;

  // Check if the author of node is user whose content you want to unpublish,
  // similarly for checking the user role: "in_array("USER_ROLE_TO_CHECK",$user->roles)"
  // To add the add check for content type, add "$node->type === 'CONTENT_TYPE'"
  if (($user_id === 'USER_ID_WHOSE_CONTENT_IS_TO_BE_UNPUBLISHED') && (!isset($node->original))) {
    // Unpublish nodes when node is created:
    $node->status = 0;
  }
}
```

This will always unpublish the content created by the user belonging to that user_ids/roles.

---

Alternatively you can use the [Override node options module](https://drupal.org/project/override_node_options): The Override Node Options module allows permissions to be set to each field within the Authoring information and Publishing options field sets on the node form.

Answer (score 1):

How about `[implementing hook_node_presave($node)][1]` in your custom module,so as example code consider the following

```
function mymodulename_node_presave($node) {
  global $user;
  // check if user has role and checking node->original is not set ensures it works only when insertion of node happens not when it is edited
  if (in_array("your_user_role",$user->roles) && (!isset($node->original))) {
    // keep the node unpublished
    $node->status = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality using below step.

- Go to Administration -> Structure -> types.
- Edit your content type.
- Uncheck 'Published' check-box under 'Publishing options' fieldset in the form.

Now, when any user except administrator of the site, create new content, by default content be unpublished. Only administrator or user which has permission to override publishing options, can published or modify publishing options.

If you would like use to access their unpublished content, you need to provide access 'View own unpublished content' to user role.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found this,with these two modules https://drupal.org/project/publishcontent
and https://drupal.org/project/override_node_options